# Add time variable to a Spatial Polygons data frame list in R

Tags: r, polygon, spatial, temporal, r-sp

I have a list of spatial polygon data frames collected on different days. I will like to add time to each day in the list so I can subset and have time/date based means for the "Z" (DDD.LFRP) variable.
Below is a subset of the list of spatial polygons:

```
[[1]]
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 128 
extent      : -127.44, -67.8964, 1.000039, 31.71804  (xmin, xmax, ymin,  ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 1
names       : DDD.LFRP 
min values  :     16.6 
max values  :    488.5 

[[2]]
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 126 
extent      : -129.04, -67.8964, 3.759985, 31.71804  (xmin, xmax, ymin,  ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 1
names       : DDD.LFRP 
min values  :       14 
max values  :    335.2
```

How do I add add time/ date to this please?
The Time stamps was created from a set of strings subset from the file names:

```
##Define date string
regexp2<-"_([[:digit:]]{12})"
DatesDL3<-sapply(names(DL3),    function(x)stri_extract_first_regex(x,regexp2))
DatesL<-gsub("_", "", DatesDL3)
DDO2<-data.frame(DatesL)
DDO3<-DDO2[["DatesL"]]
#COnvert straight to dates
Timex<-strptime(DDO3, "%Y%m%d%H%M")
Timex
[1] "2008-12-01 04:00:00 GMT" "2008-12-01 06:30:00 GMT"
```

I then tried the code written by @RobertH

```
polsdatetime <- lapply(1:length(DL3), function(i) {
p <- DL3[[i]]
p$datetime <- Timex[i]
p
})

polsdatetime
[[1]]
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 119 
extent      : -124.23, -68.26758, 2.141337, 31.80002  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 2
Error in as.matrix.data.frame(X) : 
dims [product 119] do not match the length of object [130]
```

Comment: Are you wanting to add a `timestamp` variable to each `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` within the list?

Comment: @topsig, yes; for each layer in the list but not for individual polygons within the spatial polygon dataframe layer. i.e, the two layers above will have one date/time for each layer.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you've tried, and what the output of that is?

Answer (score 1):

with `pols` being your list of SpatialPolygons and `timestamp` a vector of dates of the same length as `pols' you can do:

```
library(raster)
p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))

pols <- list(p,p)
timestamp <- c("2008-12-05 21:30:00 GMT", "2008-12-05 22:45:00 GMT")


polsdatetime <- lapply(1:length(pols), function(i) {
        p <- pols[[i]]
        p$datetime <- timestamp[i]
        p
     } )

polsdatetime     


# [[1]]
# class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
# features    : 12 
# extent      : 5.74414, 6.528252, 49.44781, 50.18162  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
# variables   : 6
# names       : ID_1,     NAME_1, ID_2,   NAME_2, AREA,                datetime 
# min values  :    1,   Diekirch,    1, Capellen,   76, 2008-12-05 21:30:00 GMT 
# max values  :    3, Luxembourg,   12,    Wiltz,  312, 2008-12-05 21:30:00 GMT 

# [[2]]
# class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
# features    : 12 
# extent      : 5.74414, 6.528252, 49.44781, 50.18162  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
# variables   : 6
# names       : ID_1,     NAME_1, ID_2,   NAME_2, AREA,                datetime 
# min values  :    1,   Diekirch,    1, Capellen,   76, 2008-12-05 22:45:00 GMT 
# max values  :    3, Luxembourg,   12,    Wiltz,  312, 2008-12-05 22:45:00 GMT
```

Comment: I think you're missing a closing `)` ?

Comment: It worked with the closing. However, it was only on the first level in the list. It came in as a variable not as a date with an error:

Comment: I have added the ) and example data to show that it works

Comment: I know it has something to do with the R spacetime package but don't know how to write it in. I am trying to create a spatio temporal object with the spatial polygons data frame not just adding the time as a variable.

Comment: Thanks, @RobertH. It finally worked. The function accepts "as.POSIXct" not "strptime". HOwever, I am still having issues using this time variable to generate a spatial points dataframe time series.